# Sorting method is giving back stack overflow

Tags: arrays, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I'm checking an array of 100,000 integers to see if they are sorted, but I keep getting a stack overflow error. I've ran this code on 1,000 and 10,000 sized arrays but when I try it on 100,000 I get the error, usually around index 84353. Is the array to big to check?
It's required that the method be recursive.

```
static boolean flgIsSorted(int[] arr) 
{
  boolean bool = true;
  int index = arr[0];
  int[] newArr = new int[arr.length-1];
  if(newArr.length > 0) 
  {
     for(int i = 1; i < newArr.length+1; i++)
     {
       newArr[i-1] = arr[i];
     }

     for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
     {
         if(index <= newArr[i]) 
         {
          bool = true;
         }
         else 
         {
           bool = false;
           return bool; 
         }  
     }
  //prints what arr will be created next
     System.out.println(arr.length-1);
     flgIsSorted(newArr);

  }
  else {      }
  if(bool == false)
    return bool;

  return bool;

}
```

Comment: Your recursion is going too deep. If you are doing a recursive call at each array element, that's going to be a problem. There are correct ways to solve problems recursively, and incorrect ways. But your code is hard to read. Please indent properly and consistently. It's all over the place. Note that the markup language here doesn't get along well with tabs for indenting.

Comment: Alright, I tried cleaning it up a bit, thanks. I also found out that when I use this method on the 100,000 int array, it works before I sort it. But after I use a sorting method, (whether it's merge or quicksort) I get the error. I've ran through all subsections of the array to see if they got sorted and it seems like they did, but still confused on why I get this error

Comment: You still have issues with the recursion. One glaring issue is that you ignore the return from the recursive call to `flgIsSorted(newArr)`. If you don't need the result, the call is of no use.

Comment: What's the purpose of `if(bool == false)
    return bool;

  return bool;`? It's the same as just `return bool;` by itself.